# Regex for selecting every white space

Tags: c++, regex

What would look regex for selecting every white space?  I've tried to do few combinations, including excluding nums, digits etc but to no avail.

Comment: Can you show us the combinations you've tried? What programming language are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question, add the tag, the regexes you tried, what you got as result, what do you expect as result ...

Comment: echo the above comment, please provide an example of what exactly you are looking for? white spaces at the end, beginning or in-between would also help in the example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about a simple

```
\s+
```

together with a match_all method or option, depending on your language?

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vh96), the good place to test regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

\s is the best for a match to a white space character. White space here would be defined as [\t\n\f\r\p{Z}].

Try this link for C++ Regex: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Answer (score 0):

If the language/environment supports it, you can use the `\s` modifier.

In perl:

```
$str = "my string that has spaces"

if($str =~ m/\s/)
{
   #it has a white space character
}
```

If you cannot use `\s` directly, you can combine all the items in the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter) into one character class. From that link:

`If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, \s is equivalent to [\f\n\r\t\v]`

Comment: I think you mean `if($str =~ m/\s/)`, you used the replacement syntax that would replace the pattern found in `$str` with `\s` (while `\s` can not be used as replacement)